# SQL Left Join logic in SAS Merge or Data step

Tags: sas

I have below two datasets and need the third dataset as an output.

```
ONE                TWO  
----------         ----------
ID FLAG            NUMB  
1  N               2  
2  Y               3  
3  Y               9  
4  N               2  
5  N               3  
9  Y               9  
10 Y

OUTPUT  
------- 
ID FLAG NEW  
1  N    N  
2  Y    Y   
3  Y    Y  
4  N    N  
5  N    N  
9  Y    Y  
10 Y    N
```

If ONE.ID is found in TWO.NUMB and it's ONE.FLAG = Y then the new variable NEW = Y 
else NEW = N

I was able to do this using PROC SQL as below.

```
proc sql;  
create table output as
(
   select distinct id, flag, case when numb is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as NEW
   from one
   left join
   two
   on id = numb
   and flag = 'Y'
);
quit;
```

Could this be done in DATA step/MERGE?

Comment: Please make an effort to solve the problem first, and post what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry dude, I gave you your one free question. Now show some work.

Comment: @HongOoi I tried with PROC SQL before posting the question here and it worked but was not able to do with data tep/merge as I have just started to learn SAS. Now I have updated the question with the PROC SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

since you have a sql step attempt here's an improvement on that

--this sql step does not require a merge--

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table output as
    select distinct *, case
                            when id in (select distinct numb from two) then "Y"
                            else "N"
                        end as new
    from one
    ;
quit;
```